# Is it possible to say that the set $D$ is discrete?

Tags: general-topology

Assume that a set $D$ has no accumulation point. Then: Is it possible to say that the set $D$ is discrete?

Comment: You can of course say it. Let me show you: «The set $D$ is discrete.» What you want to ask if it is true...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Only this result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In fact, it’s possible to make a stronger statement: $D$ has no accumulation point if and only if $D$ is both discrete and closed.

Answer (score 1):

Supose $D$ has no accumulation point, then for any $x \in D$, there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that the ball $B(x;\epsilon)$ contains only finitely many points of $D$. Call these points (other than $x$ itself) $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$, then choose
$$
\delta_x = \frac{1}{2}min\{d(x,x_i): 1\leq i\leq n\}
$$
Then $B(x;\delta_x)$ contains exactly one point, namely $x$.

This is true for any point $x \in D$. Hence, $D$ is discrete.